# Passing arguments tp python program in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have simple python file in Visual Studio Code:

```
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+', help='an integer for the accumulator')
print (sys.argv[1:])
print ("end\n")
```

I pass arguments `"--N" , "111"` when debug starts:

Content of `launch.json` in `.vscode` folder :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args":  ["--N" , "111" ]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Program prints nothing in arguments and complains regarding missing argument `--N`

What I do wrong while passing arguments in VS Code?

UPD

Parameters are passed if I run by pressing F5 on selected file. And failed if I click icon `Run Python File`:

[image]

Why no argument pass in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this
`"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]` into your `launch.json`

An example would be something like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args":  ["--N" , "111" ],
            "purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]                
        }
    ]
}
```

I was scrolling around the internet for solution and this works for me.